# DropDownButton Background scrolls out of Listview Container in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

Ive put an dropdownbutton within a listview widget and when im scrolling trough the listview it seems like the background of the Dropdownbutton is scrolling out of the listview which causes an different colored rectangle on the background of the page.

Vid: [VID Example](https://youtu.be/tNLqcCwSceQ)

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:raumbuchung/widgets/createBookingPage/roomSelectedStudySpace.dart';

import 'bookingTextField.dart';
import 'roomSelectedGenerel.dart';

class RoomSelection extends StatefulWidget {
  const RoomSelection({super.key});

  @override
  State<RoomSelection> createState() => _RoomSelectionState();
}

class _RoomSelectionState extends State<RoomSelection> {
  final List<String> items = [
    'Konferenzraum P9',
    'Konferenzraum MEX',
    'Veranstaltungsfläche SC 6.OG',
    'Aktiven Co-Working SC 6.OG',
    'Study-Space Sprintraum'
  ];
  String? selectedValue;

  Visibility textColumn = Visibility(visible: false, child: Placeholder());
  BookingTextField bookingName = BookingTextField(hint: 'Titel');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 10, 15),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Container(
            height: 600,
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      // Titel Row
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                            'Raum: ',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          )),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Container(
                                child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                    hintText: 'Raum auswählen',
                                  ),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                                  value: selectedValue,
                                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedValue = value!;
                                      if (selectedValue ==
                                          'Study-Space Sprintraum') {
                                        textColumn = Visibility(
                                            visible: true,
                                            child: RoomSelectedStudySpace(
                                                room:
                                                    selectedValue.toString()));
                                      } else {
                                        textColumn = Visibility(
                                            visible: true,
                                            child: RoomSelectedGenerel(
                                                room:
                                                    selectedValue.toString()));
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  items: items
                                      .map((String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                            child: Text(item),
                                            value: item,
                                          ))
                                      .toList(),
                                ),
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 15),
                      textColumn
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Ive tried to put the button in an container or wrap it with other widgets but nothing helps.